# IsKeyboardFocusWithin in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, focus

How to get the keyboard focus is anywhere within the element or its visual tree child elements in Silverlght?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible solutions depending on your scenario (we usually prefer more detail in a question).

First you can use the `FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()` static method to get the element that currently has the focus.  You could then use the `VisualTreeHelper` to determine if the element is with the your element.  I would normally use an extension class to make using `VisualTreeHelper` easier.  Mine is found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx).  With that class present.  Then:-

```
public static bool IsFocusIn(DependencyObject element)
{
      DependendyObject focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as DependencyObject;
      if (focusedElement != null)
      {
           return focusedElement.Ancestors().Any(e => e == element);
      }
      return false;
}
```

The second approach is to add event handlers to the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events of your element.  You can then track whenever the focus enters or leaves any control within your element.