# Prevent control loosing focus when child gets focus

Tags: wpf, silverlight, focus, controls

Ok so I have an issue where I have been trying to create a custom control in Silverlight. It is simply a button that when pressed opens a dropdown menu, however the dropdown menu is a child control. I have a property (isDropDownOpen) that controls whether the dropdown is open. I want that when the control loses focus that the property goes to false so implemented the following override in my class.

```
protected override void OnLostFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);

        Object focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
        FrameworkElement element = focusedElement as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null)
        {
            IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the control looses focus when the child control gains focus so the menu closes as soon as I click on anything other than the button. I can’t really see how to work around this, any ideas?

EDIT: Essentially what I wish to do is check if the item is a child before actually changing the property. In wpf I would do something using 'IsChild()' or '.containsFocus()' however these do not appear to e available in silverlight...

Using silverlight 5.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IsKeyboardFocusWithin in silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596742/iskeyboardfocuswithin-in-silverlight)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the following link to be a solution to my issue.

http://icircusmonkey.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/silverlight-how-to-close-the-popup-when-user-clicks-outside-of-the-control/

The solution in my case was to find the ancestor of the control (going up to the window) and subscribing an event handler to close the menu when a click is registered on the window/ancestor. Works perfectly.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link is broken now, so it's not of any real use.